# Автоматическое удаление файлов с сервера

Tags: php, сервер

Привет всем. Вот делаю веб-приложение - ресайз и обрезка картинок онлайн. То бишь пользователь загружает картинки на сервер и работает с ними. Естественно, на хостинге будут скапливаться сотни пользовательских папок. Как заставить сайт в автоматическом режиме удалять папки, время жизни которые превышает, например, 3 дня?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. При добавлении изображения на сайт создавать запись в БД с указанием текущего времени и ссылкой на картинку.
2. Создать скрипт, который обращается к БД, составляет список старых картинок и удаляет их.
3. С помощью [Cron](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) запускать вышеупомянутый скрипт на выполнение с необходимой периодичностью.

*P.S.: Для защиты сайта рекомендую почитать статьи [1](http://habrahabr.ru/post/44610/) и [2](http://habrahabr.ru/post/44615/).*

Comment: без БД не обойтись? По-моему папки тоже обладают информацией о времени создания...

Comment: Можно и без БД, но такой вариант мне кажется более гибким и надежным.

Comment: Пример кода: http://pastebin.com/XYWsXCbL

Comment: Спасибо за содержательный ответ. Удалять-то файлы - дело несложное. Надо будет разобраться в cron. Чтобы все это автоматически происходило.

Comment: Я бы не заморачивался с БД, хранить кучу инфы про все именения картинки будет накладно. Написать shell сркипт дело пары минут, посмотрите команду linux -- find, можно вырезать файлы одной строкой, второй вырезать из базы, если надо. :)

Answer (score 1):

Вообще не парься

Используй `filemtime`

Потом подсчитывай время

```
time()-@filemtime('1.png')
```

при добавлении картинок пробегайся по папкам и удаляй все старые

А вообще меньше папок плоди, а то потом замучаться можно

если много папок то прийдется базу заюзывать

Comment: filemtime — это разве не дата последней модификации? Что тогда делать с картинками, которые не были изменены после загрузки на сервер?

Comment: тс написал ресайз и обрезка картинок. :)

Comment: @thunder, по вашему - это одно и тоже? Или что вы имели в виду?

Comment: не, я к тоому, что ресайз и обрезка картинок "сгенерирует" поле mtime, Так что им вполне можно пользоваться.

Comment: @thunder,и то верно!

Answer (score 0):

Настроить крон с необходимыми параметрами удаления, например по ctime или mtime .

Answer (score 0):

Понимаю что прошло много времени, но это для тех кто пришли с поиска:

```
$cache_time = 5; // Время жизни файла в секундах
$cache_file = "cache/a.txt"; // Файл будет находиться, например, в /cache/a.txt
if ((time() - $cache_time) > filemtime($cache_file)) {
  // Если время жизни прошло удаляем файл: a.txt
  unset($cache_file);
}
```

запустит **cron** в определенное время.